# how to add an element to a list only when it is not exists already if the list is null create one?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

**input**

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "whatever1",
      "id": "ID1"
    },
    {
      "name": "whatever2",
      "id": "ID2",
      "dep": [
        "a.jar"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "whatever3",
      "id": "ID3",
      "dep": [
        "a.jar",
        "b.jar"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**output**

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "whatever1",
      "id": "ID1",
      "dep": [
        "b.jar"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "whatever2",
      "id": "ID2",
      "dep": [
        "a.jar",
        "b.jar"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "whatever3",
      "id": "ID3",
      "dep": [
        "a.jar",
        "b.jar"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in the above example

- `whatever1` does not have `dep`, so create one.
- `whatever2` has `dep` and does not have `b.jar`, so add `b.jar`
- `whatever3` aready has `dep` and `b.jar` is there so untouched.

what i have tried.

```
   # add blindly, whatever3 is not right 
   cat dep.json | jq '.apps[].dep += ["b.jar"]'
   # missed one level and whatever3 is gone.
   cat dep.json | jq '.apps | map(select(.dep == null or (.dep | contains(["b.jar"]) | not)))[] | .dep += ["b.jar"]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, let's define a helper function for performing the core task:

```
# It is assumed that the input is an object
# that either does not have the specified key or
# that it is array-valued
def ensure_has($key; $value):
  if has($key) and (.[$key] | index($value)) then .
  else .[$key] += [$value]
  end ;
```

The task can now be accomplished in a straightforward way:

```
.apps |= map(ensure_has("dep"; "b.jar"))
```

#### Alternatively ...

```
.apps[] |= ensure_has("dep"; "b.jar")
```

Answer (score 1):

after some trial and error, it looks like this is one way to do it.

```
cat dep.json | jq '.apps[].dep |= (. + ["b.jar"] | unique)'
```

Comment: This solution might be acceptable but it has several disadvantages (it involves a "sort") and deviates from the specification (e.g. consider the "untouched" requirement).